Running bun add while bun dev is already running
currently I am learning SolidJS and using bun. I wonder if there a way to run bun add command without stopping bun dev. Like in npm, I can npm install without stopping current dev server. Because right now, when I already start the dev server, it throws error this Failed to link vinxi: EBUSY when I tried to add new packages. I get tired when I have to stop and start the dev server multiple times.

That feature will be included in bun v1.1.27.
You can try the fix with canary (bun upgrade --canary)
merged pull requests url: https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/pull/13575

It would be useful to also e.g. link to a Bun PR or release note about this.
